# nginx redirect for a specific domain

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect traffic from:

```
     http://demo.foo.com/a.png
to   http://demo.bar.com/a.png
```

One caveat is that `foo.com` and `bar.com` are both the same box. So I need specify that the redirect occur for `foo.com` traffic only, to avoid a redirect loop on `bar.com` traffic.

I tried this:

```
server {
  server_name  demo.foo.com;
  return       301 $scheme://demo.bar.com$request_uri;
}
```

After waiting a minute for it to take effect... This looked promising:

```
curl -I http://demo.foo.com
```

The 301 appeared as expected. However, there are two issues:

1) running `curl -I http://demo.bar.com` also came back with a 301 redirect to `demo.bar.com` (so my server_name filter is not working)
2) after a few more minutes (~2-3) both curl commands stop working, and return a 503 Unavailable message (this may be due to a redirect loop caused by #1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are using such constraction:

```
server {
   ...

   server_name demo.foo.com demo.bar.com;

   if ($http_host = "demo.foo.com") {
      rewrite ^ http://demo.bar.com:$server_port$request_uri permanent;
   }

   ...
}
```

Comment: Adding the if statement seems to be what works, even though it is listed as "bad practice" or a "pit fall" to do so. Thanks. I did not need the server_name line.